# Rank of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm given a linear trasnformation: $T:M_2\rightarrow M^{\:}_2$ which is defined such as $T\left(X\right)=AX$, where $A$ is:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2\\ -2&4\end{pmatrix}$$

Find the rank of T?
My idea was to find the nullity of T and then use the rank-nullity theorem.

$$AX=A\begin{pmatrix}x&y\\ z&w\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x-2y&z-2w\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}=0$$

$$x=2y $$ 
 $$ z=2w
$$

Thus concluding that the Nullity of T is 2, and by that theorem rankT + nullityT = n = 4, and finally rankT = 2.

Is my solution correct and could it have been done quicker?

Comment: I very much doubt that the entries you calculated in $AX$ are correct. Check the $0$'s again. Besides that, your proof is alright. You could also have proved it, by writing each matrix as a $4$ column vector, and then rewrite $T$ in this new representation... but I don't know which one is faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, using $M_2\cong \mathbb{R}^4$ via $\begin{pmatrix}x & y\\z & w\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\end{pmatrix}$. Then
\begin{align*}&T:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4\\
&\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}x-2z\\y-2w\\-2x+4z\\-2y+4w\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-2&0\\0&1&0&-2\\-2&0&4&0\\0&-2&0&4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Now compute the Rank of $T$ as usual (for example via Gauss Elimination plus Dimension Theorem)

*NOTE*: your entries of $AX$ are unfortunately all wrong.

Comment: thank you Mr. revieuw I'm still a beginner I do not know all the rules but I learned
I mean that for a square matrix the method Utilised by the author (of the rank theorem) should, because the rank of the matrix in this case is the number of nonzero eigenvalues
 (counted by order of multiplicté) , what can assume exist by embedding the field of the coefficients in an algebraically closed field.

Answer (score 0):

Good method, bad execution.  You should find that
$$
AX = \pmatrix{x - 2z & y-2w\\-2x + 4z & -2y + 4w}
$$
Now, the system of equations for $AX = 0$ is equivalent to
$$
x = 2z, \quad y = 2w
$$
With that, we find that the nullity of $T$ is indeed $2$, and so the rank of $T$ is $4-2 = 2$, as you had stated.

I think you have found the quickest way to do this problem, but in this case it was easy to "eyeball" the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach to determining $T$’s nullity:

Each column of $AX$ is the result of multiplying the corresponding column of $X$ by $A$ and does not depend on any other columns of $X$, so if $AX=0$, then each column of $X$ considered as an element of $\mathbb R^2$ must lie in $\ker(A)$. This means that the nullity of $T$ is twice the nullity of $A$. The kernel of $A$ is easily computed by inspection or via the usual methods and is one-dimensional, so $\dim\ker(T)=2$ and $T$’s rank is thus $2$.